# jQuery UI: what files do I need?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am implementing tabs in a website.
I want to use [this](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/) jQuery UI widget. There are other uses of jQuery on the website, but not jQueryUI (only in this particular place).
So I am trying to include only the needed parts of jQueryUI.
How can I determine what minimum parts of js code have to be included?

Comment: You can unselect feature that you dont need in your jquery UI and download minified JS from http://jqueryui.com/download/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To find out just go to this webpage

1. [jQuery Ui](http://jqueryui.com/download/)
2. select Toggle all (to remove all ticks)
3. Then just check tab and it will then automatically select all the ones you require which is Core, Widget and Tabs.

You will also as always require the normal jQuery library. When you reference them the jQuery library must be first

Answer (score 7):

You'll need:

- Jquery Library

  `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>`
- Jquery UI Library

  `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>`
- Jquery UI CSS:

  `<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />`